# Nested quotes and variable concatenation

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling with a complex nested quotes statement here :

```
var name = "foo";
$("#list").append("<li data-theme='c'><a href='#details' onclick='sessionStorage.name=PRINT_VAR_NAME_HERE;' data-transition='slide'>PRINT_VAR_NAME_HERE</a></li>");
```

I am able to print the variable's value fine in the **second** position by using : "+name+"

But not sure how to get it done in the **first** position.

(I have used 'PRINT_VAR_NAME_HERE' as a placeholder for the first and second positions)

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the string-delimiters (the `"`) to break the string and concatenate the string with your variable, and escape (with the backslash) any quotes that you need to appear *in* the string itself:

```
$("#list")
    .append("<li data-theme='c'><a href='#details' onclick='sessionStorage.name=\"" + name + "\"' data-transition='slide'>"+ name + "</a></li>");
```

I am, of course, assuming that you want to quote the variable in the string, otherwise I couldn't see what the problem would be.

Comment: That worked like a charm ! Will accept your answer as soon as StackOverflow lets me do that. Thanks !

Comment: I'm glad to have been of help! =)

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue of trying to figure out how to nest quotes in a javaScript in order to generate HTML.  I was hitting a particular snag in the 'onclick' area because I was including a variable within it.  In addition, the browser was interpreting my quotes incorrectly.

The solution: You have to explicitly tell the browser which quotes you ARE using and where. And you do this by using ' for single-quote, and " for double-quotes.

Hopefully this is helpful to someone...

```
document.getElementById("item-controls-" + id).innerHTML = "<span class=\'controls\' id=\'save-control\' onclick=&#39;saveForm(\"" + id + "\")&#39;>save</span> ...
```